# Login by azure Microsoft something not work on ipad/iphone

Tags: angularjs, azure, authentication, asp.net-core, oauth

I’m working on a website which is deployed kén azure and login through azure microsoft. However, it only works on login website on computer. Whenever I login to the website by some account ( on an ipad or an iphone, it turns to signin-oidc (error 500) and then I cannot access to home page or the other pages . Anybody face to this problem and is there any solution for this? Thanks

Go to my website -> login -> azure microsoft login page open -> login by azure microsoft -> return token from azure microsoft to client -> my website check access this token -> ....

Here is the content of the BeginAuth:

```
Summary
URL: https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/SAS/BeginAuth
Status: 200 OK
Source: Network
Address: *******
Initiator:
AjaxHandlerControl.js:110

Request
POST /common/SAS/BeginAuth HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Accept: application/json
Accept-Language: vi-vn
Accept-Encoding: br, gzip, deflate
Origin: https://login.microsoftonline.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 12_4_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/12.1.2 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1
Referer: https://login.microsoftonline.com/
Content-Length: 2220
Connection: keep-alive
Cookie: ESTSAUTH=AQABAAQAAABeAFzDwllzTYGDLh_qYbH8o3IjKkzc2x1r88yy-081xaEhysFzWkgE5Giluas3rg_Dp5-Fw5bh9r4-LSLhpkG14oOyEzrVVAOR4NPQXDA5JIAKdw1Xtan0t4znDHFGqQVix1O2lkm-Y2o1nlDxmM-_swpy5MAxb7yb_b2tA_b2ZMT_MoLndRqejWKdawyYST7h5bMr6ewZNg2ts52SqlXt4BveNWIWrq5mN-xO0D4_SyqC6DPun5N_4wZoyI0I7Zj5qE9qsosdLlqgBiPi_O18QoWqRWhfjJ2B6LoteSlSaF9QgRP409lFoKBDcs5eLguK1uPGPd4X-2AXixn217QIFztBBs-EQzqiJly5xXykGURHG_PUzSaCA2akgGKyD-5QDEIKA8VCniiFHwqoX8EQGdXCUeDjC5AkBk1rxhfeAM06bJ0H-Uz6KWvV5mFNhxwmUwArKSR-QBaN5soW7k63SvO8eF31GP_u2MC4QXjZnXD8YeHclcp3qt4nHGrMJ204p85hj_Lnqj5Aio23f_4WGGJoOUN5RQIrWFP2ua81ww2Cz12xSBGPmSka7F5EeB8LNF_oYx2omVhhFVKZJapnyiuEap_DOyiEntQCsIy6SY8nNyDdkDhYAmjzSS0-uJPYkpO4JCUWq5Z8FN6wrne1hgdN5f-HaHCHPqJw1b73LxWPJMMlOb1TceHvDfDahII99BFhLcGAEZJYE28o2rBopNHNDqOz1PcryTdV4IgNmtYZwq_VtGBKUN60BRuxXbBCfXKb62j9tc4HD2fEfJ7dXLv15Zt-o9hFFeJCKc04419BG9r_yeZ0yMezJv7_8jea-JG3mjyPkVbwEfoD8nSkIAAgAEAA8AEAAA; ESTSAUTHPERSISTENT=AQABAAQAAABeAFzDwllzTYGDLh_qYbH896tJrsebgq-fyKSmZvVkIpkuag5kO86qDT_eS2hkuIxJ6npcaoiZ9um5ixOHEjDUiO6wxp5f4fWs81K6-A0RVQmVmcDA9h9G-QdBz0Hwk06y7stWRwp3SfhkmEuKdYxDhuyE7pImTl_n3Wsn3Ur3196goptzdQt7dRP9Mnplc9UH5D1yPwH5AHsN0MySAO281n3E9sdk0muJOM7cD2IKRGSnSki5wV-Tt3hCSh9WiW-pkBDXn-3T0mY33ZfAOahd_rN7nkqLNmrNIHSmTEXSd-W7WO7Hbnc5Om5-_C16FD2Y8a52xTYPt11zxp4_LNw8IHxUhsRjnCz-vGGR0rYdqN9NGvYTxxKYtXX2Ws4gs8K1yDxYIAA5GvKbqikiDdeGby75flRayIzUIfbv0N86AAhpTzI1Vr2fH1Q6_16r_g9z25A8mjTI73rr6ZxBoSLxHrw3ZnFa-tJ-meYxbJyXXZYn3AALE27UVQfM8y3EC-4kcaG7jdN0m_KTv5_aEA_ih9KBYPWe8bznfYRsGpj8lOVJRqY-YfpRBauFUsjS0dvec4JrImQM3ZRXbTuEedz5OQsAwqc5tPTI4qjcQRFwKCAAIABAAEABAAA; ch=eOAhIE0-NkRYjR4kYgO1gT7y31dmx3VL9YMxYR9WdoI; ESTSAUTHLIGHT=+cf40cdde-d9b9-4c8a-a402-a73a4ec99c66; ESTSSC=00; buid=AQABAAEAAABeAFzDwllzTYGDLh_qYbH84TKiKjYi6BuVyBpssR3qZD2fNIWjWH4IUGj1tgV1CjBekKsQGEtqYNmdMRIXd7N8BOo9vpLQC07NWlPoRa1jUH_-ayS6xTMT9xGQjDEZ1UggAA; fpc=Ah-RTB1jgiFCgCfEhHxEiA42YPZ6AgAAABNet9UOAAAAElWPKAEAAABFXrfVDgAAAA; stsservicecookie=ests; x-ms-gateway-slice=prod; clrc={%2218281%22%3a[%22MGmgPvDz%22%2c%22k+8Er6ui%22]}; brcap=1; esctx=AQABAAAAAABeAFzDwllzTYGDLh_qYbH8LpxpIlSUEu2HI0fzE_V_IRZe2RNJp-f2QqQ5Q3Ier3lWomWnATFbyAXP5tkq-U9ruARvMs7F-zosSlydkgEpjXJzyEyfRACjhZ_vKuEVUEqzKoCErpAbskdeRUTjqrMo70cB4tpzTB4GZFZonBLCTk0Ml3cUT-LLTZuhiu3Y_h4gAA
Host: login.microsoftonline.com
hpgact: 2101
canary: AQABAAAAAABeAFzDwllzTYGDLh_qYbH8a9SO3xGF3g6AWJIZDi54fWSNEiKErEt6YvrvJ3Fm-lIO4Y7kO9-ACPx-kAIHTbn_u5mhreKAsiP-Hn_b2PV7QPvjMYjHNFmOtYhXtFueCuvsxD-V2agrgXRBl82z91-Vv7ketwmG5XCIAJ4RBJBnEHiv2jAc671jIueFntKCDdwcbJ2t-karKLeSSx7VYafv5aDr8MhFDm-03Io8LpfLVSAA
hpgid: 1114
hpgrequestid: aa519c8c-30f9-46dd-95bb-ee6094414d00
client-request-id: 8fa2950c-7b79-400d-ac8c-630c65ec4c48

Response
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Pragma: no-cache
Set-Cookie: fpc=Ah-RTB1jgiFCgCfEhHxEiA42YPZ6AgAAABNet9UOAAAAElWPKAEAAABFXrfVDgAAAA; expires=Wed, 19-Feb-2020 08:39:37 GMT; path=/; secure; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: x-ms-gateway-slice=prod; path=/; secure; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: stsservicecookie=ests; path=/; secure; HttpOnly; SameSite=None
Expires: -1
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store
Date: Mon, 20 Jan 2020 08:39:36 GMT
Content-Length: 2356
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
P3P: CP="DSP CUR OTPi IND OTRi ONL FIN"
x-ms-ests-server: 2.1.9898.20 - SIN1 ProdSlices
x-ms-request-id: 0c407fdc-ec18-4822-9d91-d3c662525100
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
client-request-id: 8fa2950c-7b79-400d-ac8c-630c65ec4c48

Request Data
MIME Type: application/json
Encoding: UTF-8
Request Data:
```

Here is the content of the EndAuth:

```
Summary
URL: https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/SAS/EndAuth
Status: 200 OK
Source: Network
Address: *****
Initiator:
AjaxHandlerControl.js:110

Request
POST /common/SAS/EndAuth HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Accept: application/json
Accept-Language: vi-vn
Accept-Encoding: br, gzip, deflate
Origin: https://login.microsoftonline.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 12_4_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/12.1.2 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1
Referer: https://login.microsoftonline.com/
Content-Length: 2249
Connection: keep-alive
Cookie: clrc={%2218281%22%3a[%22k+8Er6ui%22%2c%22MGmgPvDz%22%2c%22zHWAEBZj%22]}; fpc=AqGp0xmfg8lLgos3zMYZv1E2YPZ6AQAAAD9nt9UOAAAAElWPKAEAAABzZ7fVDgAAAA; stsservicecookie=ests; x-ms-gateway-slice=prod; ESTSAUTH=AQABAAQAAABeAFzDwllzTYGDLh_qYbH8PFcC4jCAPANOfMbq-YWj9-5u5ZM2Hz4lOtVb4th1FHqBtfAlPxYXbkTjGWbI0eqbYK3yBdWUzJaf_pjfuAqipUpJKfo388tRwdsTr9CtHJCsb2Bb-gj7weggZrS9qDlSiQ5yPiNdbpi1Q3eeed7T6rOIPDkM2JzgwuQPRTy1A7OElUbdPfqV1-y03NT-Oad5niK4qIyLO3qbUiXXSWAHPvW4Qucn9u5all3U2DEgJN5oDLwy58GOvgcl3m1N6XtwA8Ty67IybRFIWQD86VrNJwoTV9PD6mXBm7LI0ITaa9a6_3V2jBkVTIgVK8BTQUPdQs5SDFD_M9ER8mLbd99HRVlw_aB0rPB_wyML3EDDtStBbbm2PpLF7-Bc9LHmNdXhVTrtUlob46GTiSput6771BBKXJ1O7fVHv85aLIHoCq31FQwDxO8CxoRa-RK1AECnEVckc8FXVUzOEpr4AzIlB85f82AyKGX0TwmssksASFUd7gCiRNVVRQCgmORCqZgW-juZjLKFBPMbS9DnavYyxTmhzNKkHSy-9cIXFfEpCXlUXyYVJSoLBvKpFY9yWaz6-G1G86YiuLIjYzJQTHv0tgq403dHQ49M10FiOPpgrtVuUQu6Vg-4UIaZ-qy8RWEFrB13CFkhalyGgFdZfVEuzUaKM1WQAQaYa0w15Zvt2rtBSJWe9lD9RN4VGDOm2fUT_h_JAUBc5IqMMurH2ZtAL5ntKaQLM7cUytZ7dzt6OPJCK1UGRfI-bRIBtnjkSD0sKeScwrGzY9kLqjYc7YiiEjx-7z3yEn5x3pCwjQUMv__dDdCA-Q8gHFtrcBQcwLaOIAAgAEAA8AEAAA; ESTSAUTHPERSISTENT=AQABAAQAAABeAFzDwllzTYGDLh_qYbH8xJRdtnbkjGoFDDkcczRP-0vt8McGva1mrQ4Hlj-urVvuUAnk3WtFW0VM9UaZC0uE3AHrqYFjQ49FnfueYD8s2uwtC89QXtud4HyBPZx7VFdcTf4nbjQqWl--UfStURhk7Jkr-hiCQo8stX1jy5xTKD91nYnkt4Jh_lhO4ul5ByQcYAiH1aWvE-2FCt1bKOxs1-DnYPhvvl9sa0s6C4Awpz7kzLn0o_FlUeVNDoQ7AU99IU6gKeetRRx8MTFUy5enxbviahbL97gIoV3FX5MuVd40d_9QCwXD2QB450NgGPRAhyM81l0bHT7anMjcDhl-7fj26i2q6EGm0LTQvRH3C3BdpJrafvkBKZaDOqdpoqgQWefiS4JAPtDRJlKCoraFryHLRKuKIwSwT_0-q0B2Wbz2eA0-uVeQoT9QRycHAIi4uWMbpSlQIoOh8uDQ4XWkKxC1qIPGH5ph6yZGr6DBs9zw8F52_ABHjQtjZeqLwOH_2tJwhHlhRjseQQ-sfPqs2unGfEqH_ea1HcT6ghJkMwKbyWw5FgO_HtElrYNn9BIQt04jPBBupWH57uw-GdKlnyk1_iUFhTIG8In4g6nfoyAAIABAAEABAAA; ch=2ZexXvpi5pBsPVR3WldndSN3Jss01W9lqt3Oo4atPto; ESTSAUTHLIGHT=+ccbda084-3cfd-4fba-a121-64822022264b; ESTSSC=00; buid=AQABAAEAAABeAFzDwllzTYGDLh_qYbH83h0-hsSMC7dM5dkdMfsldYZQhtZ_5IMn2ZWccmkXmkyQugUDrd1sqLyFIo52qI1ICYVz0_3ozkcTDV1vemApeSunFPxJEyWbLhKWIIMiRSwgAA; brcap=1; esctx=AQABAAAAAABeAFzDwllzTYGDLh_qYbH8C_SETJvY2bJWBn6b4YBwYZ7oWTYtAHOB03Kf6w7z6vx4agejzLR-KrengZwkpZuVxa46rpVJHyjKDFiK21Ze093B5qYDaOrkz3uZPgiJdYqVbjuCum0RxKS6CmtEx7u5UHUmbF28DhO-fw7SE8GiQOgk-WMKtZ5l15V323DZ2yAgAA
Host: login.microsoftonline.com
hpgact: 2101
canary: AQABAAAAAABeAFzDwllzTYGDLh_qYbH8B01oIe03wUWEzPISTHAYY9DIzppZsJdHlAJVTT_qDkwW63QTbVzZyGyuWTH8DI13YW7IQFYQyNSmc82iyDqXYnIYXKzNwTXHaKFvgefiHsMs4s_H-iKu7nbw5riTkXpshEv8RqrNzUCQ5RzPkN_DmRrl6pxzpx5PE9xy_lbhsMNJhlRHR9ydR32alGrgIUMk5jeiWnXwyn-Iv0ZeaTm_liAA
hpgid: 1114
hpgrequestid: 6046baec-30dd-4d4d-b4c0-c2a9bdd65000
client-request-id: 907865da-9681-4d95-a65a-dd40a3661f79

Response
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Pragma: no-cache
Set-Cookie: fpc=AqGp0xmfg8lLgos3zMYZv1E2YPZ6AQAAAD9nt9UOAAAAElWPKAEAAABzZ7fVDgAAAA; expires=Wed, 19-Feb-2020 09:19:24 GMT; path=/; secure; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: x-ms-gateway-slice=prod; path=/; secure; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: stsservicecookie=ests; path=/; secure; HttpOnly; SameSite=None
Expires: -1
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store
Date: Mon, 20 Jan 2020 09:19:23 GMT
Content-Length: 2356
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
P3P: CP="DSP CUR OTPi IND OTRi ONL FIN"
x-ms-ests-server: 2.1.9898.20 - SIN1 ProdSlices
x-ms-request-id: be26f84b-5386-4b04-a31f-64f06db04e00
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
client-request-id: 907865da-9681-4d95-a65a-dd40a3661f79

Request Data
MIME Type: application/json
Encoding: UTF-8
Request Data:
```

Here is the content of the failed signin-oidc content:

```
Summary
URL: https://*****/signin-oidc
Status: 500 Internal Server Error
Source: Network
Address: *****

Request
POST /signin-oidc HTTP/1.1
Cookie: ARRAffinity=b67cf4989142f516cf1224c1da63f82fb954c6d5a9d7f17d287740c0647a1f76
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Origin: https://login.microsoftonline.com
Content-Length: 1886
Accept-Language: vi-vn
Host: *******
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 12_4_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/12.1.2 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1
Referer: https://login.microsoftonline.com/kmsi
Accept-Encoding: br, gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive

Response
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Expires: -1
Date: Mon, 20 Jan 2020 08:23:38 GMT
Transfer-Encoding: Identity
Cache-Control: no-cache
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=2592000
Server: Kestrel

Request Data
MIME Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
id_token: eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6InBpVmxsb1FEU01LeGgxbTJ5Z3FHU1ZkZ0ZwQSJ9.eyJhdWQiOiJjNjA4ZjhhYi1lZjA4LTRjYjEtYjAzMy1hNzQyMjg0ODA3NmEiLCJpc3MiOiJodHRwczovL2xvZ2luLm1pY3Jvc29mdG9ubGluZS5jb20vMWZkMWRmYzQtZTVlMy00ZDM3LWFkZGItM2VjYTQxMWVjYWVjL3YyLjAiLCJpYXQiOjE1Nzk1MDgyOTMsIm5iZiI6MTU3OTUwODI5MywiZXhwIjoxNTc5NTEyMTkzLCJhaW8iOiJBV1FBbS84T0FBQUFSUWhkYzc3SWNXN2dMb0RHcUVkN2pnV3hoRDdtK29Kb0NPS3A0SkRnS3VlL3JCdno2V2NYNysvOUlYYXREWURKeUp6Y0I5MWs5SjJIbVJSZ2tUVEsyNGdWM0dLS3hteXVBTnJGUk4waDJIdS9jYVN6K1FzNUc3R21kYXJSVG5jSCIsIm5hbWUiOiJOZ29jLCBMdXUgVGhpIFBodW9uZyAoU0FMRSkiLCJub25jZSI6IjYzNzE1MTA1MzMyNTE2MTI4OC5OVGRsTkdFMU1ESXRNRGRpWWkwME1tRTVMV0ppWTJZdE1URXlaak15WW1FNU5UYzVObU16WkdJM01tSXRObU5tT1MwME5qVmlMVGd4TVRndFpqY3dOMlUxT0dJNU9EVTUiLCJvaWQiOiJkZWJlNTRlNy0wOWE0LTQ2MDItYmFlZC1jNWRjN2VkM2NiMjMiLCJwcmVmZXJyZWRfdXNlcm5hbWUiOiJuZ29jLmx1dXRoaXBodW9uZ0Bub3ZhbGFuZC5jb20udm4iLCJzdWIiOiJEV1E1Y0pEbVA3WHI2Szloakx1enNiS2RmUUs3cERWNzBYbmpYTkVmbzRjIiwidGlkIjoiMWZkMWRmYzQtZTVlMy00ZDM3LWFkZGItM2VjYTQxMWVjYWVjIiwidXRpIjoiMHdQNEIyUWhpa081WEJHYkxoRkxBQSIsInZlciI6IjIuMCJ9.MO2h7kO8I9ANFI9TgJZCVGpl0J7oxmeMQPMKM1Vt8AzXqLxN46CS1q4QlAR8x8Ca_D8IPpB277HpumUVc4vseffBJ9i_M_6I4Qqt2bzmHCcIRqTGluc8C-UlEBFvIBshOILCjVpS6feESboRTbWkIgVPfArlb03FtvS1HDinaWpAWRMPSNr40sYvF_3I7VT4wk52Ne1ZZRIhB71wAbeYzlcBlXQJA8yZhg2oGuoBy3B0V45v8f9Kskd7wIgvq0rI-kxSTKIo7pxHclNnvjDJm4J4DeAdA5dzKdmaCTzN4EMDsOZY0y1vM3UdJnM1BQkHip3FyRQ1Hj6eolbPwafdaQ
state: CfDJ8H2WPQdBhutNkjRYYA9J-dr_EWgqMxJ32ez0tMZ1rrPWWnow1tT8M7sqGJspDcOU08NK2Hhg12jGCXAuI8biXhycBguS-EZgJnh2pYPq7SE8Fin-XaF17rJDxNXCEp-B1Rw8sTVbNLo-cdaTf0tqKE01Ey2srTrQA3-5Y5EgsQnZ-PuhzykvglYxeBbV09e2wZ7Cw0AngaZBwTYrs-3ETv8sakZwXTX2gFjUy5q61MCxpdhHepRvd2lT7ZEAWNXGrzBBVoM-VM0C-Lztf65ZqNhP_0U8vgwHsxvzA47KWEGbdMLC80xoGNLO1p8zU3n9Yzkdp0fsc5z7ExBTVAexe6WBoALObVNPSWBOhR0BEdRFgkyPfWJBYBbQTqwv-C6CwBojTOI4e4GPGZfmJXvlKQg
session_state: 7f9db494-e7d2-4803-b8ec-979d0dad856f
```

[Return this page and can't go anything page on my website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Koy4J.jpg)

[image]

Comment: a long time ago I had a problem with ios too, but it was an infinite loop thanks to Apple that had changed something about cookies...let me see if I can find it and maybe give you some help

Comment: take a look: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=188165 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52544576/azure-active-directory-safari-redirection-issue/52545635#52545635

Comment: Thiago Custodio : but sometime this bug happend on windowns / android too.

Comment: then, must be something else... better you open an issue on github