# SameSite cookie setting for redirection problem

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, redirect, cookies, samesite

I am setting sameSite cookie to none to make my app(when used on iOS devices) receive cookies properly. But I still face problem receiving cookies and redirection problem exists (like, login->homepage->login->homepage.

Frontend ReactJS and backend ASP.net core.
Using Azure AD for authentication (MSAL).

Comment: I could see that you are using `SameSiteMode.None`. I refer to the [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/samesite?view=aspnetcore-6.0) and come to know that Cookies that assert `SameSite=None` must also be marked as **Secure**. Setting the SameSite property to Strict, Lax, or None results in those values being written on the network with the cookie. Setting it equal to (SameSiteMode)(-1) indicates that no SameSite attribute should be included on the network with the cookie. You could test it in your project.

Comment: If possible, try to set the options like this code sample. `options.OnAppendCookie = cookieContext => CheckSameSite(cookieContext.Context, cookieContext.CookieOptions);` See whether it works.

Comment: Thanks a lot. The problem is, even if we set our cookies with SameSite=None; Secure; they still don't be set and sent cross-domain. Looks like safari is not sending third-party cookies anymore since they introduced Privacy Preference: "Prevent cross-site tracking" (which is turned on by default). So SameSite=None is still treated as SameSite=Strict. The only solution that works rite now is turning off "Prevent cross-site tracking" on safari settings.

Comment: It is great to know you found the workaround for the issue.